# Using variation values in a template file

Tags: theming, commerce

I am building a site that uses Drupal Commerce 2 and I am attempting to build out the product details template. Our product has a variation (field_accessories) which is an entity reference to another product and I am trying to access the title, the images (first one actually), and the link to the product's detail page.

I got the title showing with

```
{{ product['field_accessories'][0]['#commerce_product_variation'].getTitle() }}
```

and I can get the sku and price with:

```
{{ product['field_accessories'][0]['#commerce_product_variation'].getPrice() }}
{{ product['field_accessories'][0]['#commerce_product_variation'].getSku() }}
```

But I need the images and url link. Based on the available methods from using kint on the product['field_accessories'][0]['#commerce_product_variation'] I tried:

```
{{ product['field_accessories'][0]['#commerce_product_variation'].get('field_images') }}
```

and

```
{{ product['field_accessories'][0]['#commerce_product_variation'].getField('field_images') }}
```

and

```
{{ product['field_accessories'][0]['#commerce_product_variation'].getField('images') }}
```

but nothing is working and all come back with null.

When I do a `product['field_accessories'][1]['#commerce_product_variation'].getFields()` I see the following:

[image: field from getFields]

Any ideas on how to access the field_images and url to that product's page? Thanks and let me know!

Comment: Ok I manager to get to the Drupal\image\Plugin\Field\FieldType\ImageItem using product.field_accessories[0]['#commerce_product_variation'].get('field_images')[0] but I can't find the URL path for the image.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer that worked for me:

```
product.field_accessories[0]['#commerce_product_variation'].get('field_images')[0].entity.fileuri)
```

And I looped over the product.field_accessories to get just the first image for each product